# Improving Performance in an MS Access Database

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access 2003 Database with more than 60 tables and 120,000 records. This DB works on the network and it is split into a back end(BE) and a front end(FE). At most two or three users use this DB at the same time.

I want to improve the performance as it is currently quite slow. Which approach will improve performance - using FE/BE or putting the whole DB on a shared folder (without FE/BE) and then using it?

Comment: Happy reading with this: http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm

Comment: I read it but I did not get my answer.Very nice article

Comment: Why would you wish to use replication which can get very complicated indeed and is intended for remote users. Is your network a WAN?

Comment: it's LAN,I thought may be Replication make performance better

Comment: Exactly how slow is this application? Is it slow when you run a simple query on a linked table with suitable indexes?

Comment: to be honest by a simple query that returns 12000 records ohne index near 12 seconds but with index 6 seconds.can I make better?

Comment: I should think so, see if this helps: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/improve-performance-of-an-access-database-HP005187453.aspx

Comment: as I understood,unsolit the DB could be a solution? correct?

Comment: Also, is the network generally slow, does file copying take a good deal of time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7611/discussion-between-remou-and-iav-babak)

Comment: I have no Problem with the Netwrork second question did not understand :(

Comment: Search Office Knowledge Base, you'll find plenty of articles there: http://support.microsoft.com/search/default.aspx?query=odbc+and+optimizing+and+tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under no circumstances should you run an unsplit MS Access app in a multiuser environment. If your app is slow, the article posted by vulkanino is a step on the way to making it faster. You should make sure that all you tables have suitable indexes, that queries use those indexes as far as possible, that forms are based on queries, not tables and that complex forms are carefully organised. For example, subform controls can be loaded with forms as required.

Comment: I super agree. Anyhow Access IS slow.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, none of your solutions will work well. You should use a sqlserver (full or express) as your backend. Then connect with odbc from the front-end. After that, look carefully at your indexes and try to move the most heavy query in storedprocedures or views in sqlserver. This will save your work on forms, reports and vba code.

Of course this scenario assumes a lot about your network (do you have a always on server pc?), about your work and purpose of your db.

Comment: There is far more work to running SQL Express than there is to running MS Access. Anyone can maintain an MS Access database, it takes some technical knowledge to maintain as SQL Server database. 120 thousand records is very small indeed, and if the database is badly designed, it will not get much better no matter what back-end is used.

Comment: Thank you both,and what about replication? could be a soulotion for me?